# Permutation cycles

Tags: proof-writing, permutations

My tasks are  the following :

**Task 1 :**

Prove that $  \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 2 & \cdots & r-1 & r \end{pmatrix}
=   \begin{pmatrix}  2 & 3&  \cdots & r & 1 \end{pmatrix} =   \begin{pmatrix} 3 & 4 & \cdots & 1 & 2  \end{pmatrix}=  \cdots  =   \begin{pmatrix} r & 1 &\cdots & r-1 \end{pmatrix}$

and conclude that there are exactly r such notations for a r-cycle

**My Attempt:**

My understand of why this would be true as follows:

You are given a permutation $f \in S_X $ such that:

$f(1) =2 , f(2) =3 ,\ldots , f(r-1) = r , f(r) =1$

So when constructing a  r-cycle, we r choices for the first element in the cycle, while the remaining  $r -1 $  elements are dictated by $f$ and hence:

$r \times 1 \times 1 \times \cdots \times 1 = r $.

**Task 2:**

if $1 \leq r \leq n $ then there are $ \frac 1r [ n(n-1)\ldots (n-r +1)]$ r-cycles in $S_n$

**My Attempt:**

I again  have some understanding of why this is true. You have a set of $n$ elements. Of which  you want to find all possible r-cycles , this is the  number of permutations of the n elements  taken r element at a time divide by r i.e. the  number of way a cycle can be represented

Can you offer any suggestions or tips on how to convert these rough ideas in fully fetched rigorous proofs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are almost done. Just put this into mathematical grammar (i.e. use the definition of a cycle by $(a_0, f(a_0), \ldots, f^r(a_0))$ and remark that $a_0$ is in a set of cardinality $r$ (namely the elements of the cycle of length $r$).
For Task 2, the argument is already formulated well. Just say that you are using the result from Task 1.

Comment: i.e $a_0 \in \{a_0 . f(a_0) ,...,f^r(a_0)\} $

Comment: If you understand you correct  by using the following definition :  $(a_0, f(a_0), \ldots, f^r(a_0))$ and noting that $a_0 \in \{a_0 , f(a_0),\ldots , f^r (a_0)\}$ and  concluding that $a_0$ can take on $r$ values?

Comment: This is rather vague in my opinion

Comment: Not exactly, given one representation by $\{a_0, \ldots\}$, another can be obtained by chosing $a_1\in\{a_0,\ldots\}$ to obtain $\{a_1, \ldots\}$

Comment: would one need to prove that?

Comment: Seems quite obvious

Comment: How are we certain that other elements are depended on $a_1$?

Comment: Well, the definition says so, since the $i$-th element of the cycle is given by $f^i(a_i)$. Since we know $f^k(b) \ne b \ \forall k < r$ we can be sure that the representation will be a different one if $a_0 \ne a_1$.